# Implement two php versions on the same ovh ftp

Tags: php, host, ovh

I have a ftp server with two applications in it. But one of these works with php7 and the other with php4. Is it possible to make these two versions cohabit together ? The two applications are totally separated (despite the fact that they are in the same ftp). The applications are hosted on a mutualised ovh server.

Thanks a lot by advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your OVH web hosting account, you can connect multiples domains or subdomains. This feature is called "multisites" into the customer panel.

At the root folder of each multisite, you can setup a different .ovhconfig file with differents configurations. So, you can use php7.0 into one multisite and PHP4.4 in another one.
https://www.ovh.co.uk/g1207.configure-php-web-hosting